# GDPR: Subscribing for advertisments using an email that a user does not own.

Tags: gdpr

Is a company GDPR compliant if user A is able to subscribe for advertisments using an email of user B, if the company does not verify the ownership of the email and still send advertisments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDPR regulations do not really care about the exact technical means. To use personally identifiable information (such as an email address) of person B, you need consent from person B (as no other ground would allow this). You don't have consent, so you're not compliant.